# PHP Query parameters in Array

Tags: php

Good day!

Iam making a query wherein the parameters will be stored in the ARRAY. My code is as follows:

```
    $conditions = array();
    if ($event != ''){
        $conditions[] = "event LIKE '%$event%'";   //ERROR HERE?
    }
    if ($event_name != 'Choose Category') {
        $conditions[] = 'event_name = "'.$event_name.'"';
    }
    if ($event_startDate != '') {
        $conditions[] = 'event_startDate = "'.$event_startDate.'"';
    }
    if ($event_endDate != '') {
        $conditions[] = 'event_endDate = "'.$event_endDate.'"';
    }

    $query = "SELECT *
          FROM eventlist 
          WHERE event_share = 1".implode(' AND ', $conditions); //IS THIS CORRECT?

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error: Query failed');
```

There's already previous questions regarding this and i've already tried most of the answers there (I've tried so many combinations already). But still I cannot produce the results I desired. My first error is the LIKE.. Also, I am having error with my query statement. What I want is to combine all the parameters based on what user desired. If the user did not input any parameters, it will be catched by my IF statements.

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code above may generate somewhat query like as follows:

```
$query = "SELECT *
          FROM eventlist 
          WHERE event_share = 1  event like '%xyz%' "
```

that is you are missing AND before event...

suggestions:
1.) it would be better if you add some error code too
2.) use following code for $query:

```
$conditions[] = 'event_share = 1';
$query = "SELECT *
          FROM eventlist 
          WHERE ".implode(' AND ', $conditions);
```

Comment: Thank you Also Mr. KoolKabin.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $query = "SELECT *
      FROM eventlist 
      WHERE event_share = 1 AND ".implode(' AND ', $conditions);
```

Comment: you might want to remove that last quote

Comment: if I put an AND there, if the user did not enter any parameter, then the "AND" is hanging..

Comment: There's a possibility that my four IF conditions will not be met.. so that AND will cause an error..

Comment: @newbie - then use `$query = "SELECT * FROM eventlist WHERE event_share = 1 AND ".(($conditions!='')?implode(' AND ', $conditions):'');`

Comment: Gah... damn I'm stupid... - `$query = "SELECT * FROM eventlist WHERE event_share = 1".(($conditions!='')?' AND '.implode(' AND ', $conditions):'');`

Comment: Wow. thanks it worked. hahaha. I've been trying to solve it for hours. Thanks. :)

Comment: @newbie you might want to try out KoolKabin's implementation too as it seems more elegant ;)